# SQL Join Not Returnig Desired Results

Tags: sql

I'm having a little trouble getting a SQL query working to give me the desired results. I have three tables. The SQL query should return all records with an employee name, along with their corresponding department name, and a division should it exist. If they do not, they should still display the employee with a Null division. Here is a link to my SQL Fiddle...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76fbb/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Comment: omg, I can't tell you how many times I tried that already. sheesh, I hate when this happens. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

use a `LEFT`join instead of a `RIGHT`join.